WooCommerce individual orders page add customer role custom field
This is sort of a follow-up question to this question that was successfully answered a while ago in
WooCommerce orders page add customer role custom column answer code.
I'm trying to see if it's possible to add some custom php to my site to allow the customer role to be seen on the individual orders page. Would there be a way to edit the code below to also show that data on the individual order page as well? Ideally I'd like this role to be only visible to admins and not the users themselves.

We expect from you, to provide in your question, a real code attempt. Note that stack overflow is not a free coding service. See How to ask

The following code can display user roles in the edit order page.
function get_user_role_name( $user_id ) {
    // Get the user object
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

    // Get the user's roles
    $roles = $user->roles;

    // Get the global WordPress roles object
    global $wp_roles;

    // Initialize an array to hold role names
    $role_names = array();

    // Loop through the user's roles and get the display names
    foreach ( $roles as $role ) {
        if ( isset( $wp_roles->roles[$role] ) ) {
            $role_names[] = $wp_roles->roles[$role]['name'];
        }
    }

    // Return the role names
    return $role_names;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_payment_info', 'gs_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_payment_info' );
function gs_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_payment_info($order){
    if ( $order->get_user_id() == 0 ) {
        echo '<b>This order was placed by a guest.</b>';
        
    } else {
        $role_names = get_user_role_name( $order->get_user_id() );
        
        // Display the role names
        if ( !empty( $role_names ) ) {
            echo '<b>User Roles:</b> ' . implode( ', ', $role_names );
        } 
    }
    
}

We are using woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_payment_info action hook, so, the user roles will display as show in the screenshot before.

